# XSL-FO: place text on odd pages only, skip even pages

Tags: xsl-fo

I have a document where I want to place text on the odd pages, and an accompanying drawing on the even pages. 
My page definitions look like this:

```
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="page_even" page-height="210mm" page-width="297mm" margin="{$page-margin}">
    <fo:region-body region-name="body" margin-top="190mm" margin-bottom="20mm" margin-left="200mm" margin-right="97mm"/>
    <fo:region-before region-name="header-even" extent="190mm" precedence="true"/>
    <fo:region-after region-name="footer-even" extent="20mm" precedence="true"/>
    <fo:region-start region-name="outside" extent="15mm"/>
    <fo:region-end region-name="inside" extent="15mm"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>

<fo:simple-page-master master-name="page_odd" page-height="210mm" page-width="297mm" margin="{$page-margin}">
    <fo:region-body region-name="body" margin-top="20mm" margin-bottom="20mm" margin-left="15mm" margin-right="15mm" padding="0pt"/>
    <fo:region-before region-name="header-odd" extent="20mm" precedence="true"/>
    <fo:region-after region-name="footer-odd" extent="{20mm" precedence="true"/>
    <fo:region-start region-name="inside" extent="15mm"/>
    <fo:region-end region-name="outside" extent="15mm"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>
```

So on the even pages I've got a really large header where I'll place the drawing. The body region is 0 mm high and 0 mm wide, so no text should fit in this region and it should automatically flow to the next page.

The text consists of some data placed in a table (17 cm wide and 1.5 cm high). On the odd pages, about 10 of these tables fit, and the 11th gets moved to the next available page. So far, so good.

My XML consists of data blocks in this vein:

```
<data id="3" name="blah" drawing="xyz">
```

I use markers to extract the contents of the 'drawing' attribute. The even page header refers to this marker, so the even page slows the drawing listed in the first data block of the odd page.

The renderer (Antennahouse) still places one table on each even page. The table is placed on top of the footer, overlapping the footer text. The table is larger than the region it is placed in, so it should be moved to the next page, but that logic fails here. 
There is an 'overlap' property, but this does not have the effect I need: there is no way to specify "don't overlap at all', just ways to handle the overlap.

Comment: I would like to see more of the setup and the content. Are the images on even pages static (the same) or changing? How are you intending to change the image every other page? Markers?Personally I would think maybe you could throw the "image" into a footnote which would not fit on the page so it would go automatically to the following page (and fill it).

Comment: I would also make a comment that having a page with "0" size body region may not get you what you "wish" to expect. I would need to dig out the spec but I believe a page with no body content could possibly be collapsed by a rendering engine. Such as if the very first block in my flow has "page-break-before" as "always", you still would (should) not get a first blank page.

Comment: I'd be surprised if empty pages get collapsed. I've made pages with no body content by placing empty blocks with "page-break-before=always" attributes (e.g. to force a couple of empty pages at the end of a chapter), this always worked as intended.

Comment: Using a footnote wouldn't work: in some cases I have to repeat the drawing. I can have one or 60 data blocks that all refer to the same drawing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different name for `fo:region-body/@region-name` in `page_even` so your flow won't flow onto even pages.

Comment: This is more a comment than a full blown answer. Consider giving feedback like this as a comment.

Comment: In a quick test, this solved the problem. So @Kris I'd prefer to leave this as an answer instead of a comment.